# Given all possible k-ary relations over an n-element set, which sentences converge to a non-zero percentage as n goes to infinity?

Tags: combinatorics, logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

For each relation, the sentence is either true or false.

Is there a taxonomy of sentences in this regard? Many seem to converge to 0 or 1, are there some that converge to values in between?

Comment: I think a significant difference between this question and that one is that we're considering all binary relations instead of just groups.

Comment: (1) I think you mean "binary function" or "binary operation", not "binary relation". (2) Can you clarify what you mean by "group axiom"? The theory of groups is usually presented with three axioms: associativity, existence of a (two-sided) identity, and existence of (two-sided) inverses. I'm fairly certain that all three of these hold with probability $0$ as $n\to \infty$. But you speak of a "taxonomy" of group axioms. By "group axiom", did you just mean "sentence in the language of groups"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman After reading the previous comments, I generalized it a bit. This almost seems to be halting-problem like situation.

Comment: Again, are you sure you don't mean $k$-ary *function* or *operation*? It is well-known that for any relational language $L$ and any $L$-sentence $\varphi$, the probability that a random structure of size $n$ satisfies $\varphi$ limits to $0$ or $1$ as $n\to \infty$, and there is an algorithm for deciding whether the limit is $0$ or $1$ for every sentence. This is called the zero-one law for first order logic (in a relational language). The situation is much more complicated for languages with function symbols, like the language of groups.

Comment: Oh yeah, in my comment I used the asker's terminology of "binary relation", but I was actually thinking of a binary function, i.e. an arbitrary magma.

Comment: @AlexKruckman I though of relations as a generalization of functions, I'm not sure if it makes a difference, since statements about them can just be rewritten into the other form. The zero-one law was what I was going for (I'll accept it as answer) Is there a name for this algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is answered by the zero-one law for first-order logic in a finite relational language. I think the best reference for this is *A Shorter Model Theory* by Hodges (Theorem 6.4.6).

Let $L$ be a finite relational language, and write $\text{Str}_L(X)$ for the set of all $L$-structures with underlying set $X$. For a natural number $n$, let $[n] = \{0,\dots,n-1\}$. Then for any $L$-sentence $\varphi$, we can define the asympototic probability $P(\varphi)$ that $\varphi$ is satisfied: $$P(\varphi) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|\{A\in \text{Str}_L([n])\mid A\models \varphi\}|}{|\text{Str}_L([n])|}.$$
This is the limit as $n$ goes to $\infty$ of the percentage of $L$-structures with a fixed domain of size $n$ which satisfy $\varphi$.

**Theorem:** For any $L$-sentence $\varphi$, $P(\varphi) = 0 \text{ or }1$.

Even more remarkably, $P(\varphi) = 1$ if and only if $M_L\models \varphi$, where $M_L$ is the Fraïssé limit of the class of all finite $L$-structures (this is a particular countably infinite $L$-structure). That is, $P(\varphi) = 1$ if and only if $\varphi\in T_L = \text{Th}(M_L)$.

Now we can give an explicit (computable) axiomatization for $T_L$ (again, see Hodges Section 6.4), and a computably axiomatizable complete theory is decidable: there is an algorithm which determines, for every $L$-sentence $\varphi$, whether $P(\varphi) = 0\text{ or }1$. The simplest form of this algorithm just searches for proofs of $\varphi$ and $\lnot \varphi$ from the axioms of $T_L$. A quantifier elimination algorithm is probably a bit more efficient.

---

It's important to note that none of the above holds for languages with function symbols.

In the comments, you wrote:

> I thought of relations as a generalization of functions, I'm not sure if it makes a difference, since statements about them can just be rewritten into the other form.

It's true that we can replace function symbols by relation symbols naming their graphs and rewrite first-order sentences in a corresponding way. The problem with this translation is that it does not preserve the count in the definition of $P(\varphi)$. That is, if $L = \{f\}$, where $f$ is a binary function symbol, and $L' = \{R\}$ is the corresponding relational language, where $R$ is a ternary relation symbol, then $\text{Str}_{L'}$ also includes $L'$-structures in which $R$ is not the graph of a function - it's way bigger than $\text{Str}_{L}$.

And if we let $\varphi$ be the sentence $\forall x\forall y\exists^! z R(x,y,z)$ asserting that $R$ is the graph of a binary function $f(x,y) = z$, then we will have $P(\varphi) = 0$. That is, in almost all $L'$-structures, $R$ is *not* the graph of a binary function. So you can think of imposing the restriction that $R$ is the graph of a function as conditioning on a measure $0$ set.

For an explicit example of the failure of the zero-one law outside the relational context, you should think about Exercise 8 from Section 6.4 in Hodges. Let $L = \{f\}$, where $f$ is a unary function symbol, and let $\varphi$ be the sentence $\forall x\, f(x)\neq x$. Then $$P(\varphi) = \frac{1}{e}.$$